# Presto SQL time difference between two dates result in hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, presto

I am facing some difficulty with calculating the time difference between two dates in Presto SQL and basically I am facing challenges when I am using date column otherwise directly put "date&time" works.

So, how can I find this and there is any specific datetype require.

Comment: Please tag only the **single** RDBMS you want your solution in!

Comment: you have to post your SQL query tried along with actual input and expected outputs.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags... feel free to add the correct on back.

Comment: Please add sample data, query you have tried and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If the presto type is really already date or timestamp (pre cast).

```
date_diff('second', from_unixtime(to_unixtime(date1)), from_unixtime(to_unixtime(date2)))
```

The from_unixtime(to_unixtime()) is not required and is very wasteful but you'll find it more flexible if multiple date/time formats are involved.

If the formats are the same you can just.

```
date_diff('second', date1, date2)
```

All that said, are you sure you really have a date/time type? Generally with these setups you really have a varchar/string that contains date/time information but on read is not actually a date/time type. In the event this is your situation you must cast the varchar/string to a date/time format before applying the operators.

```
date_parse(date1, 'formatmask')
```

Construct the format mask you need from the reference [0] below.

Lastly, on rare occasions you have to perform string manipulations before you can use date_parse to get it to a place the formatmask can work.

[0] https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html